# Mapping a bidirectional list with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, list, jpa, mapping, bidirectional

I don't understand the behavior of Hibernate when mapping a bidirectional list. The SQL statements that Hibernate produces seem not optimal to me. Can somebody enlighten me?

The scenario is the following: I have a one-to-many parent-child relationship. I map this relationship with a bidirectional list.

According to the [Hibernate Annotation Reference Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/) (Chapter: Bidirectional association with indexed collections) the mapping should look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id  @GeneratedValue private long id;
    @Version  private int version;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable=false)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn(name = "parent_index")
    List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();

...

@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @Version private int version;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable=false)
    private Parent parent;

...
```

But in this case Hibernate produces three SQL statements when persisting a parent with one child:

```
Hibernate: insert into Parent (name, version, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Child (name, price, version, parent_id, parent_index, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update Child set parent_id=?, parent_index=? where id=?
```

The third statement seems to be redundant, because `parent_id` and `parent_index` seem to be set already in the second statement.

When I change the mapping and repeat the attributes '*updatable = false, insertable = false*' to the declaration of the *@JoinColumn* in the Parent like this:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id  @GeneratedValue private long id;
    @Version  private int version;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable=false)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn(name = "parent_index")
    List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();

...

@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @Version private int version;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable=false)
    private Parent parent;

...
```

...then Hibernate seems to produce much more optimized SQL:

```
Hibernate: insert into Parent (name, version, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Child (name, price, version, parent_id, parent_index, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The client code looks like this:

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();

    Parent newParent = new Parent();
    newParent.setName("Parent1");

    Child newChild = new Child();
    newChild.setName("Child1");

    newParent.getChildren().add(newChild);
    newChild.setParent(newParent);

    em.persist(newParent);

    em.flush();
    tx.commit();
```

I am using hibernate-entitymanager 3.4.0.GA.

What am I missing? Is the Hibernate Reference Guide not correct, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I was not reading the Annotations Reference Guide thoroughly enough.

In Chapter [2.2.5.3.1.1. Bidirectional](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association) it is stated clearly:

To map a bidirectional one to many, with the one-to-many side as the owning side, you have to remove the mappedBy element and set the many to one @JoinColumn as insertable and updatable to false. **This solution is obviously not optimized and will produce some additional UPDATE statements**.

It probably would not hurt to repeat this information in [Chapter 2.4.6.2.1. Bidirectional association with indexed collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection) .

Now the question remains: if I repeat the @JoinColumn attributes 'updatable = false' and 'insertable = false' on the Parent (see code in first post) the additional update statements seem not to get produced... is this a legitimate workaround? Or does this result in another problem?